# Is it possible to use WPF and Delphi 2007/09 win32?

Tags: wpf, delphi

Is it?! Possible?

Comment: It is totally possible to do this all without any 3rd party libraries by creating your own Type Library. Here is a tutorial: https://www.dima.to/blog/?p=581

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can, with a product called "Hydra" from RemObjects:

http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx

They have a demo showing embedding a WPF graph in a Win32 application.

As Ken White notes, you can develop all your .Net stuff in Delphi Prism.  It can then be leveraged in Win32 using Hydra if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Nick. I haven't looked at Hydra, so was unaware of that capability.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at [TMS .NET Interop Tools Pack](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/xv.asp). It contains components to display xaml and xps-files in your delphi-application. How well this works - and if it works well enough to switch from vcl to xaml, I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

No. Delphi 2009 doesn't support .NET at all, and Delphi 2007 doesn't support version 3.x of the .NET framework. You can use WPF with Delphi Prism, though.

Comment: Delphi supporting .net and using .net together with delphi is two separate things.

Comment: See my comment to Nick Hodges' post. I've already been corrected, and thanked him for doing so. :-_